# How to fit data with best function (exponential function)?

Tags: fitting

I have a set of data and I am trying to find the best fitting function. However, a polynomial expansion doesn't seem to help. Should I use an exponential fit? How?

```
data={{0.99823, 1.005}, {1.0221, 1.31}, {1.0469, 1.76}, {1.0727, 
2.5}, {1.0993, 3.72}, {1.1263, 6.}, {1.1538, 10.8}, {1.1675, 
15.2}, {1.173, 17.7}, {1.18125, 22.5}, {1.19485, 35.5}, {1.2085, 
60.1}, {1.2218, 109.}, {1.2351, 219.}, {1.2377, 259.}, {1.24035, 
310.}, {1.243, 367.}, {1.2456, 437.}, {1.24825, 523.}, {1.2508, 
624.}, {1.25335, 765.}, {1.2559, 939.}, {1.2585, 1150.}, {1.26108, 
1410.}};

fit = Fit[data, {x^2, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]

Show[Flatten[{Plot[fit, {x, 1, 1.28}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotRange -> {{1, 1.28}, {-200, 1400}}], ListPlot[import[[1]]]}], 
Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Density [g/cm^3]", "Viscosity [mPas]"}]
```

Comment: Take the log of the dependent variable and you'll obtain a much better fit.

Comment: @JimBaldwin could you write some code?

Comment: you could try a transformation of your y's and then do a linear regression on the transformed values ie `lmf = LinearModelFit[MapAt[Log, data, {All, -1}], {x}, {x}]` and `ListPlot[{Exp[lmf["Response"]], 
  Exp[lmf["Response"] - lmf["FitResiduals"]]}]`

Comment: I think you'll have no problem writing the necessary one line of code.

Comment: @JimBaldwin the fact is that i don't understand your suggestion

Comment: "have a set of data" - where did they come from?

Comment: @J.M. from an excel file

Comment: ...I mean, these are measurements, no? What process generated these points?

Comment: These are taken from a book. Why is this important to find the fitting function?

Comment: Because usually the theory behind what produced your data would suggest an appropriate function to fit against, instead of having you guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`FindFormula`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)

data = {{0.99823, 1.005}, {1.0221, 1.31}, {1.0469, 1.76}, {1.0727, 
    2.5}, {1.0993, 3.72}, {1.1263, 6.}, {1.1538, 10.8}, {1.1675, 
    15.2}, {1.173, 17.7}, {1.18125, 22.5}, {1.19485, 35.5}, {1.2085, 
    60.1}, {1.2218, 109.}, {1.2351, 219.}, {1.2377, 259.}, {1.24035, 
    310.}, {1.243, 367.}, {1.2456, 437.}, {1.24825, 523.}, {1.2508, 
    624.}, {1.25335, 765.}, {1.2559, 939.}, {1.2585, 1150.}, {1.26108,
     1410.}};

f[x_] = Exp[FindFormula[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ data, x]]

(*  E^(0.0182879 - 2.93441 Cot[4.68 x])  *)

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];

Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[data]},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@
    {"Density [g/cm^3]", 
     "Viscosity [mPas]"}),
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** In subsequent evaluations of `FindFormula` I obtained a different result that corresponds to your observed result mentioned in your comment.

```
FindFormula[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ data, x]

(*  -2.93441 Cot[4.68 x]  *)
```

I suspect that this may be due to the fact that `FindFormula` has the option `RandomSeed`.

```
Options[FindFormula]

(*  {Method -> Automatic, TargetFunctions -> All, TimeConstraint -> Automatic, 
 SpecificityGoal -> 0.8, RandomSeed -> Automatic, "Monitor" -> False, 
 PerformanceGoal -> Automatic}  *)
```

The internal state of the `RandomSeed` can affect the result. Consequently, use a fixed `RandomSeed`, request multiple functions, and look at their `properties`

```
fit = FindFormula[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ data, x, 3, All, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", RandomSeed -> 1]
```

[image]

While `0.0182879 -2.93441 Cot[4.68 x]` has a lower `Error` property, `-2.93862 Cot[4.68 x]` has a higher `Score` due to its lower `Complexity`

```
keys = (fit // Normal // Keys)

(*  {-2.93862 Cot[4.68 x], 
 0.0182879 - 2.93441 Cot[4.68 x], -0.893811 + x^(7.11223 x)}  *)
```

For better error performance choose

```
f[x_] = Exp[keys[[2]]]

(*  E^(0.0182879 - 2.93441 Cot[4.68 x])  *)
```

Comment: why do you write (*E^(0.0182879-2.93441 Cot[4.68 x])*)? My output from f[x_]is only: (*E^(-2.93441 Cot[4.68 x])*)

Comment: @AndreaG - I  didn't "write" it, that is the output provided by my version (11.1.1) of Mma. What version are you using?

Comment: @AndreaG - With my version, `Options[FindFormula]` evaluates to `{Method -> Automatic, TargetFunctions -> All, 
 TimeConstraint -> Automatic, SpecificityGoal -> 0.8, 
 RandomSeed -> Automatic, "Monitor" -> False, 
 PerformanceGoal -> Automatic}` If your default options are the same then depending on the speed of the processor,  the default `TimeConstraint` could return a different result. You could try extending the time constraint.

Comment: @AndreaG - With v10.4.1 I get your results but by extending the time constraint I get the same result as v11.1.1. `f[x_] = Exp[
  FindFormula[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ data, x, 
   TimeConstraint -> 5]]`

Comment: While it is not a panacea, you might consider the common practice of using AIC to rank the model fits.  (But you'd need to use `NonlinearModelFit` to get that option.)  I wouldn't rely on "complexity" as that is a *Mathematica*-centric term.

Comment: @JimBaldwin - I agree that once `FindFormula` provides a model that `NonlinearModelFit` can/should be used to refine the parameters of the model; however, the fundamental issue is how to arrive at the model in the first place.